# Why adding string make my condition not working

Tags: reactjs

I am using reactJS and I am using some conditions to show my components. The code below is properly working. It show my success message without any problem. The FINALMESSAGE.showFinalMessage = true and FORMSTATUS["loadingForm"] = false

```
{FINALMESSAGE.showFinalMessage && !FORMSTATUS["loadingForm"] && <FinalMessageSave></FinalMessageSave>}
```

But when I add a condition with string like this:

```
{FINALMESSAGE.showFinalMessage && FINALMESSAGE.finalMessageStatus === "SUCCESS" && !FORMSTATUS["loadingForm"] && <FinalMessageSave ></FinalMessageSave>}
```

it doesnt work anymore even the FINALMESSAGE.showFinalMessage = "SUCCESS"
Here is the screenshot of my state

[image]

Comment: Check your assumptions by logging/debugging. Extract the conditional out of JSX to make it easier to log/debug. Unrelated, but choose between bracket and dot access and stick with it.

Comment: how did you change your state? a quick way to debug is to render your state variables alongside your condition.